# Internet Explorer - Scroll Magic issues

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, scrollmagic

The following code to enable content to fade out on scrolling past a trigger element is working perfectly in most tested browsers, but not in Internet Explorer.

I'm not all that experienced, but any advice will be warmly appreciated!

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var fadein_tween = TweenMax
.fromTo('#animate', 1, { opacity:1 }, { opacity:0 , ease:Power1.easeInOut  });


var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#trigger",
  trigerHook:"onLeave",
  duration: "30%"
})  
.setTween(fadein_tween)
.addTo(controller);
```

Comment: Please check your Internet Explorer version, from [this article](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/), I found the ScrollMagic support IE 9+.

Comment: Thanks for this Dillion. I tested on IE 9 yeah, but still not working. I'll keep trying things, but any further suggestions welcome!